# Python validate input against text file

Tags: python

```
    file=open('New Text Document.txt','w')
lines=file.writelines(['username:ds_jr\n','password:89120&%'])
file.close()
file=open('New Text Document.txt','r')
file.readlines()
username=input('username:')
password=input('password:')
check=['username:'+username+'\n','password:'+password]

if check == lines:
    print('hello ds_jr , welcome!')
else:
    print('not found')
```

How to compare input username and password against .txt file content.

Comment: Please don't store passwords in plain text in a .txt file. Use encryption or hash functions, but not plain text.

Answer (score 0):

```
file=open('New Text Document.txt','w')
lines=file.writelines(['username:ds_jr\n','password:89120&%'])
file.close()

username=input('username:')
password=input('password:')

file = open('New Text Document.txt')
check = file.read()

if username and password in check:
    print('hello ds_jr , welcome!')
else:
    print('not found')
```

Comment: This `if username and password in check:` probably doesn't mean what you think it does: It doesn't check if _both_, `username` and `password`, are part of the string `check`. The logic is more like `if bool(username) and (password in check):`.

Comment: Apart from that syntactic mishap it is also a highly error-prone approach, because it confirms a lot of inputs that aren't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Lookups in Python are best implemented in dictionaries. Dictionaries can also be useful for holding the information that you want to write into the file. In this case there are only two values but for flexibility let's put those into a dictionary to begin with.

Choose a format for the file that can be understood later when reading.

When the file is read, build a new dictionary to store the keywords and values.

Now you can get the user input and check the values entered against the new dictionary.

```
FILE = 'New Text Document.txt'
USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'

out_d = {USERNAME: 'ds_jr', PASSWORD: '89120&%'}

with open(FILE, 'w') as f:
    for k, v in out_d.items():
        print(f'{k}={v}', file=f)

in_d = dict()

with open(FILE) as f:
    for line in map(str.strip, f):
        if (eq := line.find('=')) >= 0:
            in_d[line[:eq]] = line[eq+1:]

username = input(f'{USERNAME}: ')
password = input(f'{PASSWORD}: ')

if username == in_d.get(USERNAME) and password == in_d.get(PASSWORD):
    print("You're good to go")
else:
    print('Incorrect username or password')
```

Now let's say that you want to keep more information in the file. All you have to do is edit the *in_d* dictionary appropriately with no need to make any other modifications to the code